# Can a variable be used in sqlite pattern match in python3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a very simple database that holds basic weather data, i.e. date (yyyy-mm-dd), max-temp, min-temp and rainfall (date, max, min, rain). I'd like to be able to use input method to assign `yyyy-mm` to a variable that can be used in below give sql query:-

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE date 'yyyy-mm%'
```

Is this possible?  If so, could you point me to a good tutorial, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check only year and month in database using **MySQL** then this query will help you:-

```
Select * from table where DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m') = "YYYY-MM"
```

For **SqLite**, you can use this tutorial to work on dates

```
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html
```

Please try this and let me know if it is not working.

Comment: Sorry, didn't work.  Got an error message no such function: DATE_FORMAT.  Oh, and thanks for fixing up my question, much appreciated.

Comment: which mysql version you are using?

Comment: Damn, I thought I put that in the question, but I obviously didn't.   Sorry about that.  I'm using SQLite3.

Comment: Sorry, still no go.  No error message, but no output either.  What I'm trying to do is replace the pattern match ('YYYY-mm%') with a variable derived from the textinput function.  I've been searching the web trying to find an answer, but no luck so far.

Comment: Oh, and many thanks for you help.  You have been most gracious.

Comment: @Griffo if my answer helps you please click on check icon to verify this answer and also up-vote. That will be very appreciated.